# Java EE (Hibernate and Spring) Backend + LAMP for front dev

Tags: java, lamp

Is it possible to use Java EE (Hibernate and Spring) as core and then use or LAMP for front dev. The idea is to have core keep back office in Java and keep front end custom development for clients in LAMP. is it a sane approach.

Comment: I think it's possible, but absolutely irrational. You may create service with Spring and Hibernate by Java, and create front-end by PHP. You have two servers, Apache Web Server and Tomcat. And your PHP app communicates with Tomcat(Spring app) by SOAP or REST or your own protocol. But I have no idea, why you won't use Java for full project. It's best solution.

Comment: It's certainly possible, but if you have to ask complete strangers whether it's a sane approach, it most likely isn't.

Comment: Just a thought... wanted to get it out of my system :) also we have worked for so  long on LAMP and now changed everything to JAVA EE spring+hibernate feel like the turnaround times are more longer. so was looking to find ways to speed things up with this combo.

Comment: Have you considered using a front-end framework like Angular.js for your "custom development" while using SpringBoot and Hibernate to serve JSON? Spring Boot allows very rapid development of JSON webservices, and Angular.js can make for rapid development of a dynamic front-end.

Comment: Right Jake will take it on board for next tech review with my team.

Answer (score 0):

Will stick to Java for now but Jake's idea looks like a frwsh appraoch for phase 2